# how to sort table rows based on color where color is applied using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, pug

I am working with node.js,jade,socket.io and jquery. I successfully created chat application and displaying online users with green colored dot and offline users with a red color dot in table. color depends on condition so I used Jquery to apply color. Now,I need to display all the online users on the top.My idea is to sort the rows by its color so that green colored will display on top.
  **Here is my code.**

```
          table
                  tr
                    td 
                      button(type="submit" class="user2" style="width:70px;text-align:left;color:blue",class="btn btn-link") All  
                    td
                      label(style="width:10px; color:#04CA3A" class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-full-dot")
                br
                each item in content.logincount    
                  - for(var i =0; i< item; i++) 
                      table#table
                        tr
                          td      
                            button(type="submit" class="user1" id="in"+i style="width:70px;text-align:left" class="btn btn-link")
                            br 
                          td
                            label(style="width:10px" , id="i"+i class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-full-dot" class="sort")
```

**Script code:**

```
           `   jQuery(function($){      
               socket.on('usernames',function(data2){
               var html='';
               var data1=[];


            socket.on('userdetails',function(data,id){  

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            if($.inArray(data[i],id) ==-1){

               $('#in'+i).val(data[i]);
               $('#in'+i).text(data[i]);
               $('#i'+i).css('color','#D62904');
            } 
            else{
               $('#in'+i).val(data[i]);
               $('#in'+i).text(data[i]); 

               $('#i'+i).css('color','#04CA3A');
            }
            }
            });
            });`
```

**Output:**   [Click to see the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbmoH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your current loop and move the connected user rows to the top of the table just after setting their color...

```
socket.on('userdetails',function(data,id) {

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

        $('#in'+i).val(data[i]).text(data[i]);

        if ($.inArray(data[i],id) == -1) { // Offline user.
            $('#i'+i).css('color','#D62904');
        } 
        else { // Online user.
            $('#i'+i).css('color','#04CA3A')
                     .closest('tr').prependTo($('#i'+i).closest('table'));
        }
    }
});
```

NOTES:

1. If `id` is a javascript array (looks like that), the javascript native function `.indexOf()` is faster that the jQuery `$.inArray()`, so you could use...

   ```
   if (id.indexOf(data[i]) == -1) { // Offline user.
   ```
2. If you put an `id` to the table of users, you can select it directly (faster again)...

   HTML

   ```
    <table id="userstable"...
   ```

   JQUERY

   ```
   var $userstable = $('table#userstable');
   $('#i'+i).css('color','#04CA3A')
            .closest('tr').prependTo($userstable);
   ```

So, putting everything together...

```
socket.on('userdetails',function(data,id) {

    var $userstable = $('table#userstable');

    for (var i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++) {

        $('#in'+i).val(data[i]).text(data[i]);

        if (id.indexOf(data[i]) == -1) { // Offline user.
            $('#i'+i).css('color','#D62904');
        } 
        else { // Online user.
            $('#i'+i).css('color','#04CA3A')
                     .closest('tr').prependTo($userstable);
        }
    }
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!